# dgri-report collect on_unchanged_config=nop

Tags: ubuntu, plesk

I have an cloud server running Ubuntu and Plesk.
Since 2 days I get the following E-Mail every hour.

```
Subject: Cron <root@server> dgri-report collect on_unchanged_config=nop
Content:
API call failed: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
error: failed to collect system info
```

Server, Plesk and Websites are running without problems. 
Maybe someone can help how to solve this issue?

Comment: There is also bug report on the [Plesk forum](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/api-call-failed-http-error-500-internal-server-error.356426/page-3) about this. Also a solution seems to be provided. Can you check if that helps you?

Comment: @codedge yes, this solved the problem. Thank you.